# Limit Medium email notifications to people I follow

Tags: notifications, medium

Is there a way to get email updates when people I follow on Medium write new posts, but not get any other email spam? This seems like such a basic feature and yet the closest option in subscription settings seems to be *We’ll email you with new stories written and applauded for by people you follow on Medium.* which would mix posts from the people I follow with anything they click the like button on.

Answer (score 6):

Currently you can't set up email or Medium notifications for new posts published by a user or publication. They do send however push notifications (iOS and Android) when a user you're following publishes a story.

What you can do instead is to create email alerts based on publication's or user's RSS feed. To do that, grab the user's RSS using this link: https://medium.com/feed/@USER or this https://medium.com/feed/PUBLICATION-NAME for publications.

Using RSS and a 3rd party service, you can create RSS to email alerts.